# Delete last 10 characters from a text file

Tags: c

Is there any way to Delete last 10 characters from a text file ?

Thanks

Comment: How about a solution that handles more than just one file encoding? I would certainly upvote such answer! :-)

Comment: @Alceu.  In pure C90? Start by setlocale(), open a temporary file, read buffer.  Use mblen() to know which bytes are part of one character.  Copy the characters to the temporary file excepted the last ten.  Refill the buffer and repeat without forgetting to output the last ten caracters of the previous buffer. Then copy the content of the temporary file to the original one.  Possible but tedious.  In C95, just use getwc() and putwc() for a more obvious solution.

Answer (score 10):

For single-byte encoding on POSIX platform you can use something like this (error handling omitted):

```
FILE *file = fopen("filename", "a");
fseek(file, -10, SEEK_END);
ftruncate(fileno(file), ftell(file));    // POSIX function
```

It is not going to work for encodings with variable-length characters, such as UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Comment: @Vijay ftruncate() is POSIX function so it is portable to POSIX platforms.

Comment: @qrdl - UTF-16 is as much a variable width encoding than is UTF-8. What you mean is the outdated UCS2.

Comment: UTF-8 is not the only problem. Other variable-length character encodings include UTF-16 (a surrogate pair represents one character, not two), shift-JIS, EUC-CN. And a UTF-8 character can occupy more than 2 bytes.

Comment: The number -10 assumes 10 bytes. That might be different than 10 characters.

Comment: Ok, ok. Indeed I meant UCS-2, not UTF-16. That's why I never use multibyte encoding. Good old ASCII (and sometimes EBCDIC) serves me just fine.

Comment: Some of us sometimes speak to foreigners ;-)

Comment: Well, English is not my first language but still 8-bit encoding (not 7-bit!) is fine with me :)

Comment: onebyone: one can still speak to foreigners in 8 bit using 'codepages'

Comment: I think the original question was about chars and not actual character codes. However, please, go no further until you read this. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html
After you are done, you are free to google for more accurate and deep introductions to the topic of encodings. I am tired of using programs written by people who still use "codepages" to speak with "foreigners".

Answer (score 3):

For something that will work under windows as well you could do something like this:

```
FILE* pFileIn    = fopen( "filenameIn", "rb" );
FILE* pFileOut   = fopen( "filenameOut", "w+b" );

fseek( pFileIn, -10, SEEK_END );
long length    = ftell( pFile );

long blockSize = 16384;
void* pBlock   = malloc( blockSize );
long dataLeft  = length;
while( dataLeft > 0 )
{
   long toCopy = (dataLeft > blockSize) ? blockSize : dataLeft;

   fread( pBlock, toCopy, 1, pFileIn );
   fwrite( pBlock, toCopy, 1, pFileOut );

   dataLef     -= toCopy;
}

free( pBlock );

fclose( pFileIn );
fclose( pFileOut );
```